# What is the best way to hang or mount photos for a showing?

Tags: galleries

I'd like to mount some of my pictures onto a wall for a simple gallery-showing. I have the physical pictures mounted to a card-stock matte. I'd like to know the best way to hang that matted picture flat onto a wood wall.

I've tried double-sided tape which works but when I remove the pictures from the wall it rips the back of the matte. I've thought about the 3m command strips but they are really expensive and not reusable. I don't want to use something that will protrude like a nail.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> "Advice is what we ask for when we
>   already know the answer but wish we
>   didn't.” - Erica Jong

Yes, they are expensive but 3M Command Strips are the right answer. If you use enough of them you can hang an image 8 feet wide, so they scale well. The remove completely cleanly. When I looked about 2 years ago, that was the best I found.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Velcro. With this would would have multiple options. So if you leave the male or the female on the wall you can keep changing the pictures. The Velcro on the back of the picture you could stick it up with abro (its a cloth like tape which you can rip with your hands) tape. This tape does not damage your pictures. But the best method is to frame them. But this can get a lil expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion I saw on LifeHacker today was to use magnets. Not a bad idea.

Comment: You will need a metallic surface to attach to, won't you?

Comment: Suggestion was to put some heavy staples into the wall and then the magnet on the picture, or get those magnets that stick to one another.